# Getter for NSInteger not working

Tags: objective-c

So I have a class with a NSInteger in it and now I want to return the NSInteger value.  For some kind of reason, the code for that is not working.  I have already declared the @property for the NSInteger class.

```
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) NSInteger numberFun;
- (NSInteger)sampleMethod {
    ...
    return sample.numberFun; 
}
```

The compiler says "Return from pointer without a cast".  I'm pretty sure that means that I'm using a C type for an objective-c method.  I want to know the work around for this.  (Though I don't want it to return a casted NSInteger as a NSNumber).

Thanks

Comment: did you @synthesize numberFun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sample compiles fine. I suggest you present a more complete example of your problem so we can figure out what you are doing wrong.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{ }
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) NSInteger numberFun;
@end


@implementation MyObject
@synthesize numberFun;
@end


@interface MyObject2 : NSObject
{ }
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyObject* sample;
@end


@implementation MyObject2
@synthesize sample;
- (NSInteger)sampleMethod { return sample.numberFun; }
@end
```

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, copy) MyObject* sample;` is confusing.  I'd suggest dropping `MyObject2` and simply showing a `main()` that allocs a `MyObject` and gets/sets `numberFun`.  (good answer beyond that)